# Conditionally updating roles on number of posts published?

Tags: wordpress

I want conditionally updating user roles based on the number of post.

As an example, when a user reaches 5 post, the subscriber role is automatically upgraded to the editor role.

How can I do this with the code below? (This code only changes its role if the user logs in.)

```
function custom_update_roles( $user_login, $user ) {
if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
if ( in_array( "translator", $user->roles ) ) {
$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user->ID, 'role' => 'editor' ) );
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
// Error.
} else {
 // Success.
}
} else {
// This user is not a subscriber.
}
}
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'custom_update_roles', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 function custom_update_roles( $user_login, $user ) {
    if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( "translator", $user->roles ) ) 
        {
        $user_id =$user->ID;
        $post_count=count_user_posts( $user_id );
            if ( $post_count>=5 ) {
              // Success.
                $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
                $u->remove_role( 'translator' );
                $u->add_role( 'editor' );
            } 
        } 

        else
        {
        // This user is not a subscriber.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'custom_update_roles', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into save_post hook, this is triggered when a post is saved.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

You get post ID within that hook, so you can easily check if post was actually published (or if just a draft), check total count of posts for the user, and change its role accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, i will look it.